# prove the set of all spheres with rational center and radius is countable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Prove the set of all spheres in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with rational center and radius is countable.

I have two ideas. Is either one better than the other?

1) let $(x,r)$ represent a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with center $x$ and radius $r$ such that $x,r \in \mathbb{Q}$ let $S$ be the set of all such spheres. $S=\{(x,r)\}$ take $f : S \rightarrow \mathbb{N}, ~f(S)=(x,r)=\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q}^2$ which is countable

2) let $A_r=\{(x,r) ~ \forall ~x \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ be the set of all spheres with a given radius $r$. since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, the number of such spheres is countable. let $S=\cup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} ~A_r$. S is a countable union of countable sets, so it is countable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to deal with the fact that a rational centre has three rational co-ordinates - so, for example you can index the spheres not by ordered pairs, but by ordered quadruples $(x,y,z,r)$. You can adapt either method to deal with this. The first is possibly more straightforward.